# How do you make a hard coded object dynamic

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I currently have a hard coded array that looks like this:

```
var aliens = [
{left: 100,  top:  100},
{left: 200,  top:  100},
{left: 300,  top:  100},
{left: 400,  top:  100},
{left: 500,  top:  100},
{left: 600,  top:  100},
{left: 700,  top:  100},
{left: 800,  top:  100}
];
```

I'd like to create a function that will dynamically create this instead of having it all hard coded in.  I've tried this:

```
var aliens = [];

    for (var x = 100; x < 900; x+=100) {
        aliens = {left: x, top: 100};
    }
```

That's doesn't increment x, though.  I'm reasonably certain I'm missing something really simple, but I don't know what it is.  I've tried making

```
 aliens += {left: x, top: 100};
```

But that didn't work either.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You should push to the aliens object:

```
aliens.push({...});
```

Working example:

```js
var aliens = [];

for (var x = 100; x < 900; x += 100) {
  aliens.push({
    left: x,
    top: 100
  });
}

console.log(aliens);
```

Comment: Thanks, KevBot!  I knew it was something I was overlooking!

Answer (score 2):

Nah. `Use push()` :

```
aliens.push( {left: x, top: 100} )
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code above is that you are re-assigning the variable `aliens`. If you were to `console.log(aliens)`, this is what you would see:
    `{left: 800, top: 100};`

Which means it went from a variable pointing to an array, to pointing to the object printed above.

As other answers have noted, there is a convenient method on the Array prototype called `.push()`. You can find documentation for that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

There is also another method of doing this that would allow you to have similar code to what you have above using array indexes:

```
var aliens = [];

for (var x = 1; x < 9; x++) {
    aliens[x-1] = {left: x * 100, top: 100};
}
```

This can be powerful when it matters what index you are "pointing" to. It should be noted that, even though this works, if you're only ever wanting to add something to the end or the beginning of the array, the push or unshift methods, respectively, should be used. However, if you wanted to change an array element in-place elsewhere (e.g the middle of the array), this could work.